# What is the best way to configure Hibernate annotations to manage a collection of historical records?

Tags: hibernate, collections, merge, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a case where I have a couple @OneToOne relationships in addition to a @OneToMany relationship between an Employee entity and Shift entity. An employee has a **Current Shift**, a **Last Shift**, and a collection of **Shifts** that represent a historical record of Shifts the Employee has performed. The below code shows how I've set up my hibernate annotations to represent this.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   @JoinColumn(name = "CURRENT_SHIFT_ID")
   private Shift currentShift;

   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   @JoinColumn(name = "LAST_SHIFT_ID")
   private Shift lastShift;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID")
   private List<Shift> shifts;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Shift {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "SHIFT_ID")
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID", nullable = false)
   private Employee employee;

   @Column(name = "START_DATE")
   private Calendar startDate;

   @Column(name = "END_DATE")
   private Calendar endDate;
}
```

Here's some example code to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
   public void test1(long employeeId) {
      Employee dbEmployee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, employeeId);

      Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();

      // create the first shift
      Shift one = new Shift();
      one.setEmployee(dbEmployee);
      one.setStartDate(startDate);
      one.setEndDate(endDate);

      // create the second shift
      Shift two = new Shift();
      two.setEmployee(dbEmployee);
      two.setStartDate(startDate);
      two.setEndDate(endDate);

      // create the third shift
      Shift three = new Shift();
      three.setEmployee(dbEmployee);
      three.setStartDate(startDate);
      three.setEndDate(endDate);

      // add shifts 1-3 to the collection of shifts that the employee just performed
      List<Shift> shifts = new ArrayList<Shift>();
      shifts.add(one);
      shifts.add(two);
      shifts.add(three);
      dbEmployee.setShifts(shifts);

      // set the last shift to shift #2
      dbEmployee.setLastShift(two);

      // set the current shift to shift #3
      dbEmployee.setCurrentShift(three);

      entityManager.merge(dbEmployee);
   }
```

In the ***Test1*** method above, I'm creating shifts 1-3 for the employee and populating the collection of shifts in addition to designating which shift was the employee's last and current shifts. When I perform the merge on the employee, my resulting database tables looks like this:

**Employee Table**

id: 1, currentShiftId: 3, lastShiftId: 2

**Shift Table**

id: 1, employeeId: 1, startDate:..., endDate:...

id: 2, employeeId: 1, startDate:..., endDate:...

id: 3, employeeId: 1, startDate:..., endDate:...

Everything looking good so far...

```
   public void test2(long employeeId) {
      Employee dbEmployee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, employeeId);

      Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();

      // create the fourth shift
      Shift four = new Shift();
      four.setEmployee(dbEmployee);
      four.setStartDate(startDate);
      four.setEndDate(endDate);

      // create the fifth shift
      Shift five = new Shift();
      five.setEmployee(dbEmployee);
      five.setStartDate(startDate);
      five.setEndDate(endDate);

      // create the sixth shift
      Shift six = new Shift();
      six.setEmployee(dbEmployee);
      six.setStartDate(startDate);
      six.setEndDate(endDate);

      // add shifts 4-6 to the collection of shifts that the employee just performed
      List<Shift> shifts = new ArrayList<Shift>();
      shifts.add(four);
      shifts.add(five);
      shifts.add(six);
      dbEmployee.setShifts(shifts);

      // set the last shift to shift #5
      dbEmployee.setLastShift(five);

      // set the current shift to shift #6
      dbEmployee.setCurrentShift(six);

      entityManager.merge(dbEmployee);
   }
```

But when I perform the ***Test2*** method above where shifts 4-6 are created and I perform a merge on the employee, this is the result:

**Employee Table**

id: 1, currentShiftId: 6, lastShiftId: 5

**Shift Table**

id: 1, employeeId: NULL, startDate:..., endDate:...

id: 2, employeeId: NULL, startDate:..., endDate:...

id: 3, employeeId: NULL, startDate:..., endDate:...

id: 4, employeeId: 1, startDate:..., endDate:...

id: 5, employeeId: 1, startDate:..., endDate:...

id: 6, employeeId: 1, startDate:..., endDate:...

So Shifts 1-3 are getting disassociated with my Employee. I understand that since I'm performing a merge where only Shifts 4-6 are in the list of shifts, that hibernate is updating the db to only map those 3 shifts and the others are getting orphaned, but what I really want is to keep those historical records in the database. I imagine something like this can be done; I'm just not doing hibernate right. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code of your services?

Comment: @Ricardo I've updated my post with code examples that I think will help illustrate what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my desired behavior by removing the `@JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID")` from the Employee class and instead using the `mappedBy` relationship property.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   @JoinColumn(name = "CURRENT_SHIFT_ID")
   private Shift currentShift;

   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   @JoinColumn(name = "LAST_SHIFT_ID")
   private Shift lastShift;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "employee")
   //@JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID") // this will try to manage the relationship
   private List<Shift> shifts;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Shift {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "SHIFT_ID")
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID", nullable = false)
   private Employee employee;

   @Column(name = "START_DATE")
   private Calendar startDate;

   @Column(name = "END_DATE")
   private Calendar endDate;
}
```

My new understanding is that the @JoinColumn annotation is used when you want that Entity to manage the relationship. Instead, by using the mappedBy property, I am able to specify that the relationship will be managed by the inverse entity. This works perfectly for my case.